# Ajax URL property with API variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

All I want to do is to be able to specify a User ID and API Key in the URL of an Ajax call:

Currently doing:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/115332174513505898112?key=AIzaFrCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s",
  context: document.body,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      //blah...
    }
});
```

However I want to be able to set the UserID and API Key dynamically so want there values in the URL: to be dynamic:

E.g.

```
var userId = 115332174513505898112;
var apiKey = AIzaSyCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s;

url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + userId + "?key=" + apiKey,
```

However, as soon as a define the variables inside the `$.ajax({` function the JavaScript stops working and I get an error of:

```
missing : after property id
[Break On This Error] var userId = 115332174513505898112;
```

What am I doing wrong, I'm sure I've done this before?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var userId = "115332174513505898112";
var apiKey = "AIzaSyCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s";
$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + userId + "?key=" + apiKey,
  context: document.body,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      //blah...
    }
});
```

Items to note:

- Quotes around the values of the `userId` and `apiKey`. (You may not need them around the `userId` value; you absolutely do around the `apiKey`.)
- You define those outside of the actual `ajax` function call.

I'm assuming the code is already inside a function, e.g:

```
function foo() {
    var userId = "115332174513505898112";
    var apiKey = "AIzaSyCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s";
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + userId + "?key=" + apiKey,
      context: document.body,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
          //blah...
        }
    });
}
```

If not, put it in one to avoid creating global variables with those `var` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You should put that values of your variables in quotes...

Additionally, you can not write any javascript code within objects - you need to declare your variables outside the object, and refer to them inside - like this:

```
var userId = "115332174513505898112";
var apiKey = "AIzaSyCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s";

$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + userId + "?key=" + apiKey,
  context: document.body,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      //blah...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Strings have to be contained within `"` (quotation marks). Also, you cannot define variables using `var` within `{ ... }` (object, not to be confused with markers of a function/loop/condition body).

```
var userId = "115332174513505898112";
var apiKey = "AIzaSyCzbKLawSPG8C0tjZDozO1bSWx49mJm13s";


$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"+userId+"?key="+api,
  context: document.body,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
      //blah...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variables (the var statements) **outside** the object `{}` and the function call `$.ajax()`.